# Cake (C# make) use .Net Framework methods in build.cake

Tags: c#, cakebuild

Maybe a dump question. [Cake](http://cakebuild.net/) states that its a build automation system that can be written in C#. I'm actually playing around a bit and now want to know if it is possible to call .Net methods in build.cake. At the time I've the following build.cake:

```js
var target = Argument("target", "Default");

Task("NuGet")
   .Does(() =>
   {
       // Get local directory
       // Get all packages.config files in local directory
       // Call nuget restore for every file
       var currentDir =  System.IO.GetCurrentDirectory(); // This doesn't work
       var allPgkConfigs = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(currentDir, "packages.config", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories); // This doesn't work

       foreach (var pgk in allPgkConfigs)
       {
           // GetNuGetPackageId(pkg);
       }
       
   });

Task("Build")
  .Does(() =>
{
  MSBuild("MySolution.sln");
});

RunTarget(target);
```

When calling `build.ps1 -target nuget` I get the following error:

```
PS C:\> .\build.ps1 -Target nuget
Preparing to run build script... 
Running build script...
Analyzing build script...
Processing build script...
Compiling build script...
Error: C:/Users/Mewald-T550/XAP_Playground/build.cake(6,26): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'GetCurrentDirectory' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

As cake already states it can't find `System.IO` how can I add this reference to cake?

I know that cake offers some build-in [file operations](http://cakebuild.net/dsl/file-operations/), but I want to know how to add .Net Framework methods to the cake script.

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling a method on a namespace

Change

```
System.IO.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

to

```
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

Tried this script and it worked just fine

```
var directory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
Information(directory);
```

That said, Cake has several IO abstractions built in

I.e. this will achieve the same:

```
var allPgkConfigs = GetFiles("./**/packages.config");
foreach (var pgk in allPgkConfigs)
{
   // GetNuGetPackageId(pkg);
}
```

If you just want the current directory you can use

```
Context.Environment.WorkingDirectory
```

or just

```
var curDir = MakeAbsolute(Directory("./"));
Information("Current directory is: {0}", curDir);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reference directive:

```
#r "bin/myassembly.dll"
or
#reference "bin/myassembly.dll"
```

See http://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/preprocessor-directives

Answer (score 0):

Reference directive
The reference directive is used to reference external assemblies for use in your scripts.

Usage
The directive has one parameter which is the path to the dll to load.

```
#r "bin/myassembly.dll"
or
#reference "bin/myassembly.dll"
```

Try make it point to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.IO.dll